# How to insert value into a record in mySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I'm trying to make email subscription , where user enters in their email and the 'null' field in mySQL gets updated to the email address provided. Here's what I have so far:

```
public boolean subscribeMember(MemberDTO memberDTO) {
    boolean isSubscribe = false;
    try {
     getConnection();
     pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT EMAIL FROM MEMBER WHERE MEMBER_ID = ?");
     pstmt.setString(1, memberDTO.getMemberId());
     rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
            
         if (rs == null) {
     pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE MEMBER SET EMAIL = ? WHERE MEMBER_ID = ?");
         pstmt.setString(1, memberDTO.getEmail());
     pstmt.setString(2, memberDTO.getMemberId());
     pstmt.executeUpdate();
     isSubscribe = true;
     }
            
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
     getClose();
    }
    return isSubscribe;
    }
```

And here's what I have for subscribePro:

```
<%
    request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
    
    MemberDTO memberDTO = new MemberDTO();
    memberDTO.setMemberId(request.getParameter("memberId"));
    memberDTO.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
        
    if (MemberDAO.getInstance().subscribeMember(memberDTO)){
%>
    <script>
            alert ("Thanks for joining our mailing list!");
        location.href = "main.jsp";
    </script>
<%
    }
    else{
%>
        <script>
            alert ("You are already on our mailing list!");
        location.href = "main.jsp";
    </script>
<%
    }
%>
```

Even though the email field in mySQL is null, it keeps running else. What should I fix?

```
if (rs == null) {
     pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE MEMBER SET EMAIL = ? WHERE MEMBER_ID = ?");
```

For this part I've tried "if (rs.next())"

I've also tried (INSERT INTO MEMBER VALUE ? WHERE MEMBER_ID = ?);

Comment: `executeQuery()` does not return `null` for empty result sets. It's pointless to update a row after you verify it doesn't exist. `insert ... where` is not a thing (what could it possibly mean?).

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me where you define rs == null, but I think that first you check if it exists and if it exists you update.
I just replaced the rs == null code with rs.first() which checks if there is a record.
Then I close the resultSet and the statement to then update.

```
public boolean subscribeMember() {
    boolean isSubscribe = false;
    try {
        getConnection();
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT EMAIL FROM MEMBER WHERE MEMBER_ID = ?");
        pstmt.setString(1, memberDTO.getMemberId());
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

        if (rs.first()) {
            rs.close();
            pstmt.close();

            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE MEMBER SET EMAIL = ? WHERE MEMBER_ID = ?");
            pstmt.setString(1, memberDTO.getEmail());
            pstmt.setString(2, memberDTO.getMemberId());
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
            isSubscribe = true;
        } else {
            rs.close();
            pstmt.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        getClose();
    }
    return isSubscribe;
}
```

Comment: Can you add some notes, to explain where and how your solution fixes the question's problems? In other words, notes to make your answer more useful for future visitors to this question.